# Mounted lvm volume not passed to container

Tags: docker

I'm running out of space on my docker container so I decided I'll create lvm volume on host, mount it to /mnt/data and pass it to docker using

`docker run -v /mnt/data:/mnt -i -t fedora:wrt /bin/bash`

But when I do that, my /mnt dir inside container appears empty, if I look at it via host, I can see files. I tried using

`docker run -v /etc:/mnt -i -t fedora:wrt /bin/bash`

and I can see hosts /etc files in container /mnt. I then tried passing hosts /boot which is normal xfs partition

`docker run -v /boot:/mnt -i -t fedora:wrt /bin/bash`

and I can see hosts /boot files in container /mnt

Is there a way of passing mounted lvm volume path to docker container?

p.s. I'm running docker 1.4.1 with `--storage-opt dm.metadatadev=/dev/vg/docker_metadata --storage-opt dm.datadev=/dev/vgdocker_data`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running Docker under Fedora 20 or 21?  A recent change to the systemd unit for Docker set `MountFlags=private`, which means that any mounts you make on your host *after* starting the docker daemon will not be visible to docker containers.  For details, see:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1185423

There is a fixed package available, but it hasn't hit the main repositories yet.  You can get it by running:

```
yum --enablerepo=updates-testing upgrade docker-io
```

And then:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Oh hey, according to the email I just got the update is actually live in the stable updates repository now.  So a simple `yum upgrade` should get it.

Comment: thanks very much for your help, restarting docker after the mount solved the issue!

Comment: Larsks Tomas D :what is the diff between mounting a host lvm on docker container vs using a docker lvm plugin

Comment: @user1050619 you should probably post that as a new question.